Proving Factorability of Limits
I was reviewing my Calculus proofs and realized I am missing any sort of proof justifying the factorability of limits.
Example:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)}$$
Now, of course this gets solved as so:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)}=\lim_{x \to 1}(x+1)=\lim_{x \to 1}(2)=2$$
As a formal property (to be proven) this would likely be:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)\cdot g(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$$
I know on a graph this is a removable discontinuity but I don't know how that could help the proof.
A related proof, which I keep thinking might help but I am unsure of, follows:
Old Proof
$$f\text{ is continuous at }0\implies\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{xf(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$ Assume $f$ is continuous at $0$

$0<\epsilon$ Assumption

$0<\delta$ Assumption

$0<|x-0|<\delta$ Assumption

$0<|x-0|$

$0<|x|$

$0\neq |x|$ Order Trichotomy

$0\neq x$ Positive Definiteness

$\displaystyle \frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}=\frac{x}{x}\cdot f(x)$ (Existence in $\mathbb{R}$ proven by 8)

$\displaystyle \frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}=f(x)$

$f(x)-f(x)=0$

$\displaystyle \frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}-f(x)=0$

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}-f(x)\right|=0$ Positive Definiteness

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$

$\forall\epsilon>0\forall \delta>0(0<|x-0|<\delta\implies\displaystyle \left|\frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}-f(x)\right|<\epsilon)$ Discharge Assumption

$\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0(0<|x-0|<\delta\implies\displaystyle \left|\frac{x\cdot f(x)}{x}-f(x)\right|<\epsilon)$ Universality implies Existence

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{xf(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ Definition of Limit


I don't know if this is the right path to solve for the afformentioned proof:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)\cdot g(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$$
Another path may be to just use L'Hôpital's rule but I am unsure if its proof or a necessary derivative proof for it was derived from factoring.
I have been looking everywhere for this proof so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Conceptually, the limit only requires information around the limit point (in a punctured neighborhood) is doesn't include the info in the point. Around the point f(x)g(x)/g(x) = f(x). So the limit is the same, because it can not detect the difference.

I think your proof overcomplicates matters a fair deal. Ultimately,[1]
$$
\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L
\iff
(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(0<|x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)
$$
so
$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)\\
&\iff
(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)
\left( 0<|x-c| < \delta \implies \left| \frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)}-\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right|<\varepsilon \right)
\end{align*}$$
But clearly[2], provided $g(x) \ne 0$ for $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \setminus \{c\}$,
$$
\left| \frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)}-\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right|
= \left| f(x)-\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right|
$$
Now, suppose $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists with $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then we may find $\delta > 0$ so that
$$
\left| \frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)}-\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right|
= \left| f(x)-\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right|
= |f(x)-L|
< \varepsilon
$$
Namely, the $\delta$ in question here - that will conclude the result for the ratio - is the same $\delta$ as used in the supposition $L$ exists.

Aside [1]: The above work assumes $c,L$ are finite. I'll leave investigating the cases where one or both may be infinite to the reader.


Aside [2]: The astute reader will realize that there is some handwaving here for some particularly not-nice functions. For instance, with $c=0$, consider $g(x) := x \sin \frac 1 x$. This is well-behaved in the sense that $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, but evades the handwaving and is ill-behaved in that $g(x) = 0$ infinitely many times in any interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ with $\delta > 0$. One immediate way to avoid problems like these is to reformulate the limit definition topologically, in that you can loosen the constraints from open punctured balls $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\setminus \{c\}$ to open sets. More precisely, let $f$ have domain $D$, and $D_{\ne c} := D \setminus \{c\}$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L\\
&\iff
(\forall \text{ open nbhs $V$ of $L$})
(\exists \text{ an open nbh $U$ of $c$})
\Big( f(U \cap D_{\ne c}) \subseteq V \Big)
\end{align*}$$
I'm not really sure how to handle this directly with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ offhand, though, I may have to think about it.



Another path may be to just use L'Hôpital's rule but I am unsure if its proof or a necessary derivative proof for it was derived from factoring.

This makes too many suppositions on the functions involved. Note that, to use L'Hôpital's rule, you would need
$$
\lim_{x \to c} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to c} g(x)
$$
and both are $0$ or $\pm \infty$. (And in turn also that $g'$ and $f'g+g'f$ even exist and the corresponding limit of ratios exists and so on. The property should hold in weaker circumstances than this, e.g. just $f,g$ having a limit as $x \to c$[3].)

Aside [3]: A realization this gave me in addition to Aside [2]: If $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) \ne 0$,  then there is a neighborhood about $c$ - say, a $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ - on which $g$ is nonzero, which may help with the proof. Consider proving this result an exercise. However, I believe the result you wish to prove shouldn't even require $g$ to have a limit, e.g. $g(x) := \sin \frac 1 x$, so even this much is too strong an assumption.

